# GNU screen: How to rename current window via shell commands?

Tags: shell, command-line, gnu-screen, gnu

I have an interactive shell (assume `dash`) running under a GNU screen session. Is it possible to rename the "current" window via commands issued to the interactive shell? If so, then how?

By contrast, if I wanted to accomplish the same thing via GNU screen keybindings, then I would type `CTRL+a` followed by `A` to bring up the `Set window's title to:` prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run any `screen` command (the ones that are or can be bound to keys) with `screen -X`.

So:

```
screen -X title 'New title'
```

Would set the title of the current window, same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>:</kbd> `title`<kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by the new title.

See `info screen title`, `info screen options`, `info screen 'Command Index'` for details.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd> will tell you what command is bound to each key.

To set the title of another window, see the `at` command.